# Create Project Log(History) Module in symfony with event dispatchers

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I'm developing a project management tool in Symfony, right now I'm creating a module to recording the logs i.e, to capture every event like New project create, task create, task status changes, deletion of projects and task, etc.

I have a log table where I have planned to insert new rows whenever any of the above event occurs. But for doing this, I need to go into each controller and call the log model to execute the insert query. Its almost like I'm going to work on all the actions in the controller again for appending this code. is there any other way to call the model only once using some event dispatcher like class in Symfony.

Comment: you can try working with mysql triggers, apply/remove the trigger to enable/disable module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad your are using Propel, there is a bunch of plugins and/or behavior for tracking what happend to your object. I will give you a list of what I've found:

- [pmPropelObjectLogBehaviorPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/pmPropelObjectLogBehaviorPlugin): Maintains a class changelog (the changes of each instance).
- [AuditableBehavior](http://carpe-hora.github.com/AuditableBehavior/): Add ability to log activity for propel objects
- [propel-listener-behavior](https://github.com/gossi/propel-listener-behavior): Makes you attach listeners to propel generated objects that inform you about updates on those.
- [ncPropelChangeLogBehaviorPlugin](https://github.com/CraftyShadow/ncPropelChangeLogBehaviorPlugin): a Behavior for Propel objects that allows you to track any changes made to them.

Answer (score 0):

[JMSAOPBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) does exactly that.

If I may suggest, I think it's better to add custom events for each action, with this way you can extend your app with more listener without losing control. If you use doctrine you can also work with [doctrine event system](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html)